# Java Serialization Required or not

Tags: java

As per serialization definition it is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.

Everything is clear from the definition except trasfering object over network. Is serialization is the only way for a java object to get transfered over netowrk?

In context of webapp there are many pojo classes which does not implement serializable interface but still we access objects of those classes from client. Does app servers or JVM handles serialization for these classes?

Comment: You need to differentiate between serialisation as a concept which makes an Object byte transferable and Java serialisation as a specific implementation. Converting an Object into XML, String or JSON is also making it transferable but does not use Java serialisation.

Answer (score 2):

Your classes don't really need to implement `Serializable` in order to transfer them across the network, because there are a lot of different forms of serialization and java's built-in one is actually not so great. Why ? Because the receiving end **must** also be a **java** application and it must have a compatible version of the class you are transferring.

More portable and flexible way of transferring your data across the network is to [marshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) them to XML/JSON, which can be consumed from any system, no matter whether it's java, c++, python or anything else (and as you have might already guessed - the objects do not need to implement `Serializable` in order to be (un)marshalled from/to to XML,Json, etc.).

Also there are a lot of other serialization frameworks which are accomplishing this task much better than the java's built-in serialization mechanism. An example would be: Google's Protobuff, Apache Thrift, Avro, Kryo and many other.

> In context of webapp there are many pojo classes which does not implement serializable interface but still we access objects of those classes from client. Does app servers or JVM handles serialization for these classes?

No, this is handled by the application, or by the framework you are using. For example Jax-RS implementations would use some library like `Jakson` to marshal the objects to/from Xml/Json behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

`Serializable` is required for objects stored in your session, if you want to use persistent (surviving app server restarts) and/or shared (across multiple app servers) sessions.

Data transfer to clients is usually not done by Java serialization (JSON/XML), as others have already explained.